# Can't type Turkish characters in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I can't type *some of the Turkish characters* in desktop version of the Internet Explorer.

I tried to explain the situation below. How can I fix this?

- When I press the key `ş`, it types `_`.
- When I press the key `ş` with `Caps Lock On` or `Shift + ş` it types `^` instead of `Ş`.
- When I press the key `ı`, it types `1`.
- When I press the key `i` with `Caps Lock On` or `Shift + i` it types `0` instead of `İ`.
- `ğ` (`Ğ` for capital) key doesn't work at all.

There is no problem when typing in address bar of the Internet Explorer. Also there is no problem when using other apps/programs or metro version of the Internet Explorer.

I have Turkish-Q keyboard layout and Windows 8.1.1 Pro x64 Turkish installed and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17498. And I've installed all Windows updates.

**UPDATE:** There is no problem in private browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate/reproduce the problem by using a different browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc). This will give you a better idea if the problem relies in IE or the OS itself.

In IE, make sure the page encoding is set to Turkish or Unicode (or try both).

Also, try a different webpage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I said there is no problem with any other programs including Firefox, Opera and metro version of IE. It happens in all webpages I've tried with IE. I also tried setting page encoding to Turkish (Windows), Turkish (ISO) and Unicode (UTF-8) but it didn't work.